# Can an email hyperlink be used to edit a field?

Tags: workflow, hyperlink, edit

Is is possible to have a hyperlink in a SharePoint email that automatically edits a field (selecting a check-box for example) which will allow the workflow to continue?

My colleagues would like to be able to simply approve a request by clicking a link in their email, rather then logging into the site and clicking a check-box then submit. The plan is that the hyperlink will cause a check-box to be selected, which will automatically enter an approval date (InfoPath rule) and then submit the changes. From there the workflow will notify budget approval, etc. I haven't been able to find anything in SharePoint Designer that is allowing this to happen.

If it matters I am using SharePoint designed 2010 to create the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

WonderLaura Rogers http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=247 has a great solution for 'lazy' email approval.

Users click 'reply' on a email and when the email is sent to a second list on SharePoint, then a workflow starts to do the approval.

Comment: This is actually what we also did in a project I worked on. The only problem with that (but this is actually a more general problem related to any mail based solution) is that often mail clients will not well support html-based mail layouts, so if your "alert" has to also display a preview of the data, you are better checking what mail client you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a secondary workflow whose only job it is to check that checkbox. This workflow will be triggered by a link which you can make as follows:

1) First create a workflow to update any list item in the SharePoint site List.
In the workflow settings click the "Allow this workflow to be manually started" and leave other checkboxes unchecked.

2) Publish the workflow, then go to the list to which this workflow is associated, select any item and then from the item menu select workflows. This will lead you to the workflows form attached with this list.

3) Click on your workflow that you created earliar to update item and this will redirect you the workflow start form.

4) Copy the url of this form from the address bar. This would be like
yoursite/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={9a6f5d9b-f075-43a3-a940-dafd1191477b}&ID=117&TemplateID={7b6230c2-8e22-4e7d-b167-6e68bce3a22c}&Source=yoursite/yourlist/forms/allitems.aspx

This url contains List={guid of list}, ID item id list item, TemplateID={GUID of the workflow} and source={after completion of the workflow it will redirect to this url}

Steps and explanation taken from [here](http://sharepointerz.blogspot.nl/2012/05/run-workflow-from-hyperlink-in.html)

In your approval workflow you can build the IniWrkflIP.aspx URL so that it contains the correct item ID.